# Cómo enviar un correo desde un email ingresado en un formulario usando phpmailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo un formulario como el de arriba, estoy usando phpmailer, pero no se como hacer que el correo se envie desde el email proporcionado, el destinatario ya lo tengo predefinido, el código que uso es el siguiente:

```
<?php

require_once('phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');



$mail = new PHPMailer(); 

$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

$mail->IsSMTP();

$mail->SMTPAuth = true;

$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';

$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';

$mail->Port = 587;

$mail->Username   = "micorreo";

$mail->Password   = "password";

$email_to = "micorreo";
$email_subject = $_POST['asunto'];
$email_copy = $_POST['email'];
$body = $_POST['comments'];
$name = $_POST['nombre'];

$mail->SetFrom($email_copy, $name);


$mail->AddReplyTo($email_copy,$name);

$mail->AddAddress($email_to, 'SITAP');  

$mail->Subject = $email_subject;

$mail->IsHTML(false);
$mail->Body($body);


if(!$mail­>Send()) {
echo "Error al enviar el mensaje: " . $mail­>ErrorInfo;
} else {
echo "Mensaje enviado!!";
}
?>
```

Comment: Todo parece correcto. ¿Da algún error?

Comment: @A.Cedano no manda error, pero el correo no llega.

Comment: ¿La dirección está funcionando? ¿Revisaste en la carpeta spam? ¿Revisaste el log de php por si está dando algún error?

Answer (score 1):

Te dejo un fragmento de código para implementar la clase PHPMailer. En mi caso necesitaba enviar el mismo correo a varios destinatarios de forma oculta, por lo que la variable `$recipients` almacena un array clave-valor formado por la dirección de correo electrónico y el nombre del destinatario.

```
include('class.phpmailer.php');
include('class.smtp.php');

$correo = new PHPMailer();

$correo->SMTPDebug = false;                         // Habilita la depuración del envío
$correo->isSMTP();                                  // Indica que correo se enviará usando SMTP
$correo->Host = 'smtp.dominio.com';                 // Dirección SMTP del servidor de correo
$correo->Port = 587;                                // puerto SMTP del servidor de correo
$correo->SMTPAuth = true;                           // Habilita el uso del autenticado SMTP mediante usuario y contraseña
$correo->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                        // Tipo de cifrado que requiere el servidor
$correo->Username = 'nombre@dominio.com';           // Usuario del servidor de correo
$correo->Password = 'contraseña';                   // Contraseña del servidor de correo
$correo->CharSet = 'UTF-8';                         // Codificación para los mensajes enviados
$correo->From = 'nombre@dominio.com';               // Correo electrónico que estamos autenticando
$correo->FromName = 'nombre';                       // Nombre del remitente

$correo->Subject = $subject;
$bodyReceived = str_replace("\n", "<br>", $bodyReceived);
$body = 'Código HTML con el cuerpo del mensaje';
$correo->msgHTML($body);                            // Crea el mensaje a partir de una cadena HTML

// Se envía el correo a la misma dirección que la envía para poder meter en CCO (BCC) todas las direcciones de envío de manera oculta para los destinatarios
$correo->addAddress('nombre@dominio.com', 'nombre');
$correo->clearBCCs();
foreach($recipients as $valor) {
    $correo->addBCC($valor['email'], $valor['name']);
}

// Inicia una conexión con el servidor SMTP
$correo->smtpConnect(
    array(
        'ssl' => array(
            'verify_peer' => false,
            'verify_peer_name' => false,
            'allow_self_signed' => true
        )
    )
);

if(!$correo->Send()) {
    return 0;
} else {
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Quizás debas de incluir la clase class.smtp.php?te dejo algo de código que use para  PHPMailer ,si te sirve,no agregue las funciones de destinatario ,ni de enviar por las dudas en el código que te dejo.
Y recuerda que si usas gmail,debes de configurar la cuenta para poder enviar e-mails masivamente. Saludos y suerte.

```
include_once 'lib/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php';
include_once 'lib/phpmailer/class.smtp.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 1;
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
$mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port       = 465;
$mail->Username   = "correo@gmail.com";
$mail->Password   = "password";
```